# Does sum of random variables remain independent?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Suppose we have random variables $X,Y,Z$ such that $X,Z$ are independent, and $Y,Z$ are also independent. Is $X+Y$ independent from $Z$ ?

I cannot find a counterexample, and I do not see how to prove it.

Comment: Yes, i think so.

Comment: That is also what I thought/ hoped for. Idea how to prove it?

Comment: Maybe not, seeing a counter example below...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Toss a fair coin three times.  Let $X$ be $1$ if the number of heads on the first and second tosses is odd, $0$ otherwise.  Similarly for $Y$ with the first and third tosses, $Z$ with the second and third.  Then each pair $(X,Y)$, $(X,Z)$ and $(Y,Z)$ are independent, but $X+Y$ and $Z$ are not independent: in fact $X+Y = 1$ if and only if $Z = 1$.

Comment: Indeed, $P(X+Y=1,Z=1)=\frac{1}{2}\neq P(X+Y=1)P(Z=1)=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: I asked the question because I was trying to solve http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/564144/independent-chi-squares-mean-independent-non-central-chi-square 
The statement would follow if the statement at the top was correct (but it isn't) because $c'A_0Y$ and $Y'A_1Y$ are independent.